# Leaving some bits in the port vector disconnected. Verilog module instantiation

Tags: verilog

Lets say I have a Verilog module with bit vector ports. How do I 
    instantiate it with some bits left unconnected?

I tried something like  this but it didn't work:

```
module sub (in,out)
input [3:0] in;
output [3:0] out;
endmodule

module top;
wire [1:0] a1;
wire [1:0] c1;

sub Sub1(
.in[2:1](a1[1:0]),
.out[2:1](c1[1:0])
 ); 
endomdule
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be much easier to just declare signals of the correct size and use a continuous assignment

```
module top;
  wire [1:0] a1;
  wire [1:0] c1;

  wire [3:0] pin;
  wire [3:0] pout;

  assign pin[2:1] = a1;
  assign c1 = pout[2:1];
  sub Sub1(
           .in(pin),
           .out(pout)
          ); 
endomdule
```

In general, it is not a good idea to leave input ports floating. You could use a concatenation in the assignment, or directly in the port connection.

```
sub Sub1(
               .in({1'b0,a1,1'b0}),
               .out({pout[3],c1,pout[0]})
              );
```

SystemVerilog has a net aliasing construct that makes thing even simpler

```
module top;
  wire [3:0] pin;
  wire [3:0] pout;

  alias pin[2:1]  = a1;
  alias pout[2:1] = c1;
  sub Sub1(
           .in(pin),
           .out(pout)
          ); 
endomdule
```

Comment: +1 for the assigning to some value if not needed. And to add to floating inputs, some synthesis/place and route tools will error due to not knowing how to connect this, particularly if that level is a hard macro.

Answer (score 3):

Found LRM reference on why you cannot connect parts of ports.
LRM 1800-2012 Section 23.3.2.2 Connecting module instance ports by name:

The port_name shall be the name specified in the module declaration. The port name cannot be a bit-select, a part-select, or a concatenation of ports.

Comment: Hi Harsha, welcome to stack overflow! Your answer here does not directly address the user's question and would likely be better suited as a comment on a more fully-fleshed out answer or the question itself. :)

Comment: Hi Victoria, the question was how to instantiate bits of ports and how to leave bits of port unconnected, but the LRM states we cannot do that, and I pointed out the reference from LRM which does not allow us to do that. Let me know if there are any concerns I will modify it accordingly :)

Comment: Hey Harsha, it might be useful to add some more context to your answer. For example how does it relate or add to the other answers already posted previously? Is there something about the other answers that isn't correct and this is a better solution? If you're just adding more information to another answer then this would be more appropriate as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot connect/disconnect parts of a port. You can do it with the whole port though. so, in your case you nedd to split your port in several parts, something like the following:

```
module sub (in1, in2, out1, out2);
   input [2:1] in1;
   input [1:0] in2;
   output [2:1] out1;
   output [1:0] out2;
endmodule

module top;
   wire [1:0] a1;
   wire [1:0] c1;

   sub Sub1(
    .in1(a1[1:0]),
    .in2(),
    .out1(c1[1:0]),
    .out2()
    ); 
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

My code connect 4-bits to module's 8-bit outputs, upper/lower even middle part.
It does work, but what the hell is the 's'(or anything)?
It works in both Quartus Prime 18.0pro and Lattice Diamond 3.10(Symplify Pro).

```
module dff8
(
    input clk,
    input [7:0] a,
    output reg [7:0] b
);
    always @ (posedge clk) begin
        b <= a;
    end
endmodule

module top
(
    input clk,
    input [7:0] x,
    output [3:0] y,
    output [3:0] z
);

    dff8 u0 (.clk(clk), .a(x), .b({y,s,s,s,s}));
    dff8 u1 (.clk(clk), .a(x), .b({s,s,s,s,z}));
endmodule
```